# Slick slider sync situation

Tags: css, slick.js

I'm using slick's "Slider Syncing" feature, and if slidesToShow == the total number of slides, the .slick-current class in the nav is **not** shifted when the top carousel is slid.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="slider slider-for">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="slider slider-nav">
    <div><p>1</p></div>
    <div><p>2</p></div>
    <div><p>3</p></div>
    <div><p>4</p></div>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant js:

```
jQuery('.example2 .slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.example2 .slider-nav'
}); 
jQuery('.example2 .slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.example2 .slider-for',
  centerMode: false,
  focusOnSelect: true
});
```

jsFiddle demonstrating the problem is here: http://jsfiddle.net/xd2h934n/

How can I get the .slick-current class to be moved in this case?

Answer (score 3):

I used slick's built-in afterChange event to grab the iteration and manually applied it to the nav:

```
jQuery('.slider-for').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, direction){
    jQuery('.slider-nav .slick-active:eq('+slick.currentSlide+')').addClass('slick-current').siblings().removeClass('slick-current');
});
```

h/t @jiwebdev

Answer (score 2):

This keeps getting marked as fixed on GitHub, but it still doesn't work.

This JS should do it:

```
var slides = $(".slider-for .slick-track > .slick-slide").length;
$('.slider-for').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  var inFocus = $('.slider-for .slick-current').attr('data-slick-index');
  $('.slider-nav .slick-current').removeClass('slick-current');
  $('.slider-nav .slick-slide[data-slick-index="' + inFocus + '"]').addClass('slick-current');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**mike_freegan**'s answer was very helpful, however, it does not address the advancement of navigation slider (in terms of actually advancing the slides). I adapted his answer by triggering a click event on the nav element that should be made current, instead of just applying the requisite class to it (thus firing the other events/callbacks):

```
var slides = $(".slider-for .slick-track > .slick-slide").length;
$('.slider-for').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  var inFocus = $('.slider-for .slick-current').attr('data-slick-index');
  $('.slider-nav .slick-current').removeClass('slick-current');
  $('.slider-nav .slick-slide[data-slick-index="' + inFocus + '"]').trigger('click');
});
```